# PS4 Fortnite expects me to have a mouse - where can I change this?

Tags: ps4, controllers, mouse, fortnite-battle-royale

Today when I'm in Fortnite game type select or the lobby, a mouse pointer appears in the top left-hand corner and the controller doesn't work. I gave in plugged in a mouse and tried to find where the setting is to select "controller only - no mouse or keyboard", but I can't find it.

Does anyone know where it is? On the internet, I can only find pages where people complain about unfair advantages and nothing about settings.

Answer (score 3):

Bizarre solution to the problem, but it appears to work.

1. Use a mouse to navigate to your locker, and select a dance.
2. Then hold the touchpad on the PS4 controller like the "hold to chat" at
   the bottom of the screen suggests.
3. Then press the O button on the controller.

The mouse pointer disappears and the controller works again.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I just figured out how to fix my sons. I ended up logging out of his account, logging back in and then closing out of the Fortnite application.

In order to log out of your Fortnite account on PS4, you first have to press the Home button on your controller. Then, highlight the tile on your home screen, followed by Options, and then select Close application.

Once I did this, I then proceeded to go back into Fortnite using the controller and while it did show the cursor at first- it ended up working completely using the controller!!!

VICTORY! I hope this helps you all!!! :D